# OSX HotCorner behaviour

Tags: spaces, expose

I'd like to know if there is a function that allows a hotcorner to trigger 'minimize current window in focus'. There is an app that I use on PC that ha this and I find it very useful.

I'd be open to 3rd party apps to get this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a very functional utility called [CornerClick](http://gschueler.github.io/CornerClick/) that allows for a variety of usages for each HotCorner (including minimize current app in focus).

This handy little gem of an app allows for a little more functionality than the default features of HOtCorners offered in OSX.